# When does aws sns sms SENDERID gets changed from custom-id to aws's default-id "NOTICE"?

Tags: sms, amazon-sns, sender-id

I am using aws sns for sending sms to Indian phone numbers since last two months.I am using PHP SDK for api calls.

I had sent 7000+ successful messages with custom senderid relating to our company name.But since last 4-5 days same clients/phone no.s are receiving messages with aws's default senderid "NOTICE".

I am publishing messages to a topic to send sms. Now in past few pushed messages all clients got default senderid, while in few pushed messages only few clients got default id while others got my custom id.

So, where is the problem?

Comment: facing the same issue here. Though AWS doesnt have India marked as 'YES' in their [supported countries page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html), custom sender ids did work for India until recently. Let me know if you can any more insight into this.

Comment: I talked to aws support team and they are saying same thing that they do not guarantee custom senderid in INDIA. It was working previously because some carriers of their are supporting customid while others not.

Comment: So are you using any other service for SMS that supports senderID? which one?

Comment: you can google for this. For now I'm using [msg91](http://msg91.com) for INDIAN recievers and aws for Inernational. But msg91 costs 150%-180% compared to aws.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your destination phone number is in India, your Sender ID must be registered to be able to work. You can request to register a Sender ID by opening a support ticket with AWS support (which has no cost).

Other countries require no registration, thus, some deliveries will work by just adding a sender ID value to your publish request.

You might successfully get a working sender ID to an Indian destination depending on the route the message takes to reach an end user. However, the right course of action (given technology partners and provider regulations) is to register the sender ID before using it with AWS (which is why it's not marked on the website).

**Disclosure**: I work at the AWS team for Mobile Messaging.

Comment: I opened a support request. It has been more than 15 days. They says they are working on it in each reply. But no reality till today.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you're not having an optimal experience. This process usually takes time. I will relay this information to our team and hopefully it will expedite your request. Happy coding.

Comment: @pnv I have registered my sender id with Aws support but still the received message shows NOTICE SMS as the sender name. What else is needed for setting sender id to be displayed as sender in the text message while having targeted audience as Indian?

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya unfortunately, I'm not in that team anymore. You still need to specify your registered Sender ID in your publish context. If you still experience issues, you should try opening a support ticket with AWS to further investigate this issue. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have entered a valid Sender ID, so no spaces and at least one letter?

Also it's important to know that not all countries support a custom Sender ID. See documentation from AWS bellow:

> (Optional) For **Sender ID**, type a custom ID that contains up to 11
>   alphanumeric characters, including at least one letter and no spaces.
>   The sender ID is displayed as the message sender on the receiving
>   device. For example, you can use your business brand to make the
>   message source easier to recognize.
>
> Support for sender IDs varies by country. For example, messages
>   delivered to U.S. phone numbers will not display the sender ID. For
>   the countries that support sender IDs, see [Supported Regions and
>   Countries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html).
>
> If you do not specify a sender ID, the message will display a long
>   code as the sender ID in supported countries. For countries that
>   require an alphabetic sender ID, the message displays *NOTICE* as the
>   sender ID.
>
> This message-level sender ID overrides your default sender ID, which
>   you set on **the Text messaging preferences** page.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html

Comment: yes i am sure senderid is correct. In one of my campaign, my one phone got default senderId, while another phone got custom-id. This message was published to topic where my both phone no.s were subscribed.

Comment: Few days back Custom-id was working properly, means no problem should be related to country.