# Set Sender ID for AWS SNS SMS for Indian Numbers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using AWS SDK 3.0 to send SMS via AWS SNS for indian numbers. The SMS are working fine. However its not picking up the Sender ID instead shows something like DM-NOTICE or sometimes something else.

Any pointers in this direction would be much appreciated.
I'm already defining the Sender ID in message attributes.
Please refer the code below :

```
'MessageAttributes' => [
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
            'DataType'    => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Company Brand',
        ],
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
            'DataType'    => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
        ]
    ],
```

Apparently the AWS doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html shows that Sender ID is not supported for India, however just wanted to know if I'm looking at it wrong or if there's any work around to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to someone working for "AWS team for Mobile Messaging" We need to request AWS support to register SenderID "for free".

Didn't work for me, no way to contact support on my basic support plan and no response in their support forums.

[When does aws sns sms SENDERID gets changed from custom-id to aws's default-id "NOTICE"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953243/when-does-aws-sns-sms-senderid-gets-changed-from-custom-id-to-awss-default-id)